# Как узнать сколько минут прошло начиная с 2021-01-29 21:55:21.165643 до datetime.now() ,

Tags: python, время, datetime

Имею строку, которую надо преобразовать и сравнить с текущим временем

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

tim = "2021-01-29 21:55:21.165643"
re = time.strptime('2021-01-29 21:55:21.165643', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

sleep(5)
re1 = time.strptime(str(datetime.now()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

print(re1-re)

#TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'time.struct_time' and 'time.struct_time'
```

Comment: Используйте `datetime.strptime`.

Comment: изи...................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = "2021-01-29 21:55:21.165643"

date1 = datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
date2 = datetime.now()

delta = date2 - date1

print(delta.total_seconds() // 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

tim = "2021-01-29 21:55:21.165643"
re = datetime .strptime('2021-01-29 21:55:21.165643', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

re1 = datetime .strptime(str(datetime.now()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

print(re1-re)
```

Comment: Так у вас же результат не в минутах...